# python if statement fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, if-statement

I'm trying to check a simple flag to be true or false, but my IF statement fails and it doesn't give me the correct result, Hope someone can help!

I'm using (in python3.6) this url

```
    https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=usdt-btc
```

for a get request and the data it should return looks like this (from URL in browser):

```
    {"success":true,"message":"","result":{"Bid":18362.00000000,"Ask":18399.00000000,"Last":18362.00000000}}
```

Here is my program:

```
    import sys
    import time
    import requests
    import json
    import os

    BTCtick = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=usdt-btc'
    reqBTC = requests.get('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?        market=usdt-btc').text
    BTCdata = json.loads(reqBTC)

    testResult = BTCdata['success']
    print("=============================")
    print("success content: ", BTCdata['success'])
    if (testResult == 'True'):
        print("IF: success flag is TRUE")
    else:
        print("IF: success flag is FALSE")
    print("=============================")

    print("result content: ", BTCdata['result'])
    print("Bid: ", BTCdata['result'] ['Bid'], sep='')
    print("Ask: ", BTCdata['result'] ['Ask'], sep='')
    print("Last: ", BTCdata['result'] ['Last'], sep='')
    print("=============================")
    exit()
```

Output in the console looks like this:

```
    =============================
    success content:  True
    IF: success flag is FALSE
    =============================
    result content:  {'Bid': 18420.0, 'Ask': 18439.99999999, 'Last': 18439.99999999}
    Bid: 18420.0
    Ask: 18439.99999999
    Last: 18439.99999999
    =============================
```

Any idea what I'm missing here? I'm sure it is simple
Please please help me, I'm somewhat new to python and kind find out what's wrong, I have been reading a lot the last two days, but could not find the issue!

Comment: you use text `"True"` but maybe it should be boolean value `True`

Comment: Just noticed, thanks @chris

Comment: `True` != `'True'` != `'true'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json.loads()` would convert the `true` to the Python's boolean `True` ([conversion table for the reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders)).  You just need to check for the truthiness of the `testResult` value instead of comparing it with a string `'True'`:

```
if testResult:
    print("IF: success flag is TRUE")
else:
    print("IF: success flag is FALSE")
```

In other words, here is what happened when you compared `testResult` to a `'True'` string:

```
In [1]: testResult = True

In [2]: testResult == 'True'
Out[2]: False
```

Comment: Thank you @alecxe, that saved my day :-D. Much appreciated and very informative, I didn't know I could check it like that. I guess another approach could be to define TRUE and FALSE and then check against that, but it looks like it's already part of python and pre-defined?

Comment: @ForumStudiologe yeah, right, don't overcomplicate and follow the documentation. Thanks.